# PHP Post array empty

Tags: java, php

Currently having trouble accessing some variables in the $_POST array of a server side script.

Context: I'm submitting some values to a mySQL server from an android device using PHP. 
When i "Create a new route" the php and java is working fine, for example:

Building a list of variables to post:

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("startLat", startLat));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("startLong", startLong));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("endLat", endLat));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("endLong", endLong));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("waypoints", waypoints.toString()));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("rating", rating));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("difficulty", difficulty));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("enjoyability", enjoyability));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("count", count));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sum", sum));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("countDiff", countDiff));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sumDiff", sumDiff));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("countEnjoy", countEnjoy));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sumEnjoy", sumEnjoy));
```

I then call my method to post them:

```
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, HTTP.UTF_8));
            //System.out.println(httpPost.getURI().toString());
            //System.out.println(httpPost.getEntity().toString());
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
```

And this works fine and the values are available to the PHP script in the $_POST array.
The problem i'm having is when I do the exact same process, using the following (Note in this case i'm "updating a route" and so there are a few less variables, this is reflected in the PHP script for updating a route.:

```
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("rating", Double.toString(currentRating)));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("difficulty", Double.toString(currentDiff)));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("enjoyability", Double.toString(currentEnjoy)));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("count", Double.toString(currentCount)));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sum", Double.toString(currentSum)));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("countDiff", Double.toString(currentDiffCount)));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sumDiff", Double.toString(currentDiffSum)));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("countEnjoy", Double.toString(currentEnjoyCount)));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sumEnjoy", Double.toString(currentEnjoySum)));


            JSONObject jsonEdit = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_edit,
                    "POST" +
                    "", params);
```

The $_POST array is empty on the php script server side. I realise this may be a little vague but i hope you understand. i'm doing the exact same process of sending data for both methods, however the latter is empty.

Answer (score 2):

You have the old `==` vs `equals` issue, spiced with `String` interning.

This is the culprit

```
if(method == "POST"){
```

Should be

```
if(method.equals("POST")){
```

The first method works with plain String objects. Any `"POST"` instance results in true, when compared to any other `"POST"` instance (look up String interning to get to know why). However in the latter case you have something funny in there:

```
JSONObject jsonEdit = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_edit,
                "POST" + //Ooooops, what is this?
                "", params);
```

Now you compare `"POST"`== `"POST"+""` ... This does *not* compare them by content, but by reference! And the second one is a different one, resulting in a `false` from the comparison...